# directing all output of a perl script to file and screen

Tags: perl, logging, stdout, stderr, log4perl

I have a perl script that uses log4perl to log all output to screen and file.
Problem is, certain output does not get directed to log4perl.

Script -

```
use strict;
use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all';
use Log::Log4perl;
use File::Find;

my $log_conf = "log4perl.conf";
Log::Log4perl::init($log_conf);
my $logp       = Log::Log4perl->get_logger();
my $dirSource  = 'C:\box';

sub doFileList {
    $logp->info('doing dir compare');
    find( { wanted => \&process_file, no_chdir => 1 }, $dirSource);
}

sub process_file {
    if (-f $_) {
        print "This is a file: $_\n";
    } else {
        print "This is not file: $_\n";
    }
}

#main
$logp->info('start');
eval { doFileList(); };
if ($@) {
    $logp->error( 'error: ', $@ );
}
$logp->info('stop');
```

Log4perl config -

```
log4perl.rootLogger              = DEBUG, screen, file

log4perl.appender.screen         = Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
log4perl.appender.screen.stderr  = 0
log4perl.appender.screen.layout  = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.screen.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%M:%L] %p  %F{2} - %m%n

log4perl.appender.file          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.file.filename = log/compare.log
log4perl.appender.file.mode     = append
log4perl.appender.file.layout   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%M:%L] %p  %F{2} - %m%n
```

Here is the output on screen/ide -

```
2013/03/04 11:56:28 [main:::29] INFO  DirCompare\DirCompare.pl - start
2013/03/04 11:56:28 [tools::dircompare::doFileList:16] INFO  DirCompare\DirCompare.pl - doing dir compare
This is not file: C:\box
This is a file: C:\box\test01.JPG
This is a file: C:\box\test02.JPG
2013/03/04 11:56:28 [main:::34] INFO  DirCompare\DirCompare.pl - stop
```

Here is the output in log file -

```
2013/03/04 11:56:28 [main:::29] INFO  DirCompare\DirCompare.pl - start
2013/03/04 11:56:28 [tools::dircompare::doFileList:16] INFO  DirCompare\DirCompare.pl - doing dir compare
2013/03/04 11:56:28 [main:::34] INFO  DirCompare\DirCompare.pl - stop
```

I know i am using print statements instead of log->info, but i would like the log4perl config to be such that all output of the script, irrespective of how it is generated, is directed to log4perl.

any ideas on how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used 'IPC::Run3' to capture output of any commands/functions that couldn't be captured by log->info/error. I then printed this captured output to log->info/error.

Just to clarify, what i was trying to do above is to capture output of commands executed within the perl code, and redirect that output to log.

Answer (score 1):

sub process_file{} is compiled as part of the main package. You have only told this to print to stdout. Add another statement underneath to print to the log. So you have two print statements, one for the screen and one for the log.

The IO::Tee module creates a filehandle object for multiple filehandles, so you could print to the one and all the handles contained would recieve the output. But passing in an object that opens a filehandle and prints to it into a filehandle that also does this might get buggy.